# Searching Nested Document

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am having trouble searching nested documents using the `elasticsearch_dsl` and `elasticsearch` libraries in Python.

I can successfully perform searches on top-level (i.e. non-nested) parts of the documents, but all of my attempts to search the nested portions fail for one reason or another.

I have scoured StackOverflow & the web for a definitive guide to searching nested documents using Python, but keep coming up short.

Here is a sample document that I am using:

```
{"username": "nancy",
"codeData": [
 {"code": "B1", "order": "2"}, 
 {"code": "L4", "order": "1"}
  ] 
}
```

I have 7 documents in an index, which I have mapped like this:

```
request_body = {
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },

    'mappings': {
        'testNesting': {
            'properties': {
                'username': {'type': 'text'},
                'codeData': {'type': 'nested',
                                  'properties' :{
                                      "code" : {"type":"text"},
                                      "order" :{"type":"text"}
                                      }
                                    }
                                 }
            }
        }
    }
es.indices.create(index = "nest-test6", body = request_body)
```

Performing the following search works correctly:

```
s = Search(using = es).query("match", username = "nancy")
response = s.execute()
print(response.to_dict())
```

Now, I want to try searching for documents that have code = "B1" within "codeData".

I have listed the sources that I've tried to use at the bottom of this question. My hope is that this can become a definitive guide that people can reference when trying to query nested documents using Python.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
q = Q("match", code = "L4")
s = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "codeData", query = q)
```

Above results in a Transport Error (400, failed to create query), and then lists the query itself with a bunch of \n after each item.

```
q = Q("match", **{"codeData.code"" : "L4"})
s = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "codeData", query = q)
```

Above results in a syntax error on line 1.

```
s = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "lithologyData", query = **Q{"match":{ "lithology":"L4"}})
```

Above results in a syntax error as well.

I've tried several other approaches - but changed my data structure, and so listing them here won't make sense in the context of the above document.

I have no idea how to go about querying these nested objects. There are several pieces of information I feel I am missing:

1. What are the Q/F keywords, and how to I use them?
2. I understand that I have to specify the path to the queried term by using level1.nameOfObjectBeingQueried - given this is not a suitable keyword in the Python libraries, how do I handle it?

If there are any other sources I am missing, I would really appreciate someone pointing me towards them!

### Additional Attempts Which Failed

```
s1 = Search(using = es).query("match", username = "nancy")
q1 = Q("match", lithologyData__lithology = "L4")
q2 = Q("match", **{"lithologyData.lithology":"L4"})
s2 = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "lithologyData", query = Q("match",lithologyData__lithology="L4"))
s3 = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "lithologyData", query = q1)
s4 = Search(using = es, index = "nest-test6").query("nested", path = "lithologyData", query = q2)
response = s1.execute()
response2 = s2.execute()
response3 = s3.execute()
response4 = s4.execute()
```

Response 1: Works

Response 2: Fails with:

```
TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to create query: {\n  "nested" : {\n    "query" : {\n      "match" : {\n        "codeData.code" : {\n          "query" : "L4",\n          "operator" : "OR",\n          "prefix_length" : 0,\n          "max_expansions" : 50,\n          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,\n          "lenient" : false,\n          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",\n          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,\n          "boost" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    "path" : "codeData",\n    "ignore_unmapped" : false,\n    "score_mode" : "avg",\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}')
```

Response 3: Fails with:

```
TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to create query: {\n  "nested" : {\n    "query" : {\n      "match" : {\n        "codeData.code" : {\n          "query" : "L4",\n          "operator" : "OR",\n          "prefix_length" : 0,\n          "max_expansions" : 50,\n          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,\n          "lenient" : false,\n          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",\n          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,\n          "boost" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    "path" : "codeData",\n    "ignore_unmapped" : false,\n    "score_mode" : "avg",\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}')
```

Response 4: Fails with: 
`TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to create query: {\n  "nested" : {\n    "query" : {\n      "match" : {\n        "codeData.code" : {\n          "query" : "L4",\n          "operator" : "OR",\n          "prefix_length" : 0,\n          "max_expansions" : 50,\n          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,\n          "lenient" : false,\n          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",\n          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,\n          "boost" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    "path" : "codeData",\n    "ignore_unmapped" : false,\n    "score_mode" : "avg",\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}'`)

#### Other Resources Examined

[ElasticSearch Nested Query Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

- Issue here is that it only describes how to use the REST API to do this query. In the descriptions about why the elasticsearch_dsl and elasticsearch Python libraries were made, they specifically mention difficulties sending the JSON structures directly. Although, they often cite the potential for user error, I think that there are additional aspects that I do not understand.

[Github Issue on ElasticSearch_DSL py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/304)

- Here they suggest unpacking the dictionary because you can't use "level1.level2" as an argument. However, the creator agrees that this is far from ideal. This question is from 2014, and based on other answers there seems to be a better way now, but I can't find details

[ElasticSearch_DSL Python Documentation](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html)
- Although this is useful, there is not a single example of a nested search/query in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

to query a nested field you seem to have the right approach with:

```
q = Q("match", codeData__code="L4")
s = Search(using=es, index="nest-test6").query("nested", path="codeData", query=q)
```

Any `__` in a kwarg passed to `Q` will be translated to `.` internally. Alternatively, you can always rely on python kwarg expansion:

```
q = Q('match', **{"codeData.code": "L4"})
```

which should work just as well, your example just had an extra `"` in there, that's why it was rejected by python.

Comment: Hi Honza - thank you very much for your reply. I noticed the extra " after I posed this question, and corrected it, however I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I just added the 4 queries I have tried in an edit to the main question, but to no avail. I am also not sure how to interpret the error :(.

Comment: HI Honza, do you know how to query with multi codes? I tried to do smth like `Q("match", codeData__code=["L4", "L6"])` but it didn't work

Comment: @eduzen you can use two queries OR'd together - `q = Q("match", codeData__code="L4") | Q("match", codeData__code="L6")` or you can use a special query that can handle multiple values like `terms` etc